# Getting data in a folder with Python to provide excel files to Power BI

Tags: python, import, powerbi, powerquery, schedule

I have been trying to do this but I wonder if this possible in the first place.
I have a power bi file on my computer, which is taking a file in a folder each day in a specific folder.
I would like to be able to use a python script to automatically feed this execel file to the PBI file that I have, each day, at a given time.

I have found the following code, but I am encountering issues, despite having installed pip.

```
pbixrefresher <WORKBOOK> [-workspace <WORKSPACE>] [--refresh-timeout <REFRESH_TIMEOUT>] [--no-publish]
```

Is what I am doing actually possible, or is it not possible?

Comment: Looks like a rather fragile solution. Why don't you sync your Excel file to SharePoint and then schedule a dataset refresh in the PBI Service?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why is it fragile? Is what you are suggesting this possible without a gateway? What if I do not have sharepoint? Is it possible in something like teams for example?

Comment: It's fragile since you need to schedule a Python script that runs the PBI Desktop GUI and your local computer needs to be running and at the same time you can't use PBI Desktop for other purposes. Quite some restrictions, right? On the other hand: SharePoint is free, MSTeams is based on SharePoint and you don't need a gateway to refresh from SharePoint/MSTeams.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Teams is based on sharepoint? This is really interesting! So this will work? I put my file two teams and it is ok? But what if new files arrive days after day? Will BPI know that the last one is the good one? I have been investigating, and onedrive seem to be a potential perspective as well. I cannot use PBI while the Python script is running?

Comment: SharePoint (the server) and Onedrive (the interface) are 2 sides of the same coin. If you sync an updated file to Teams/SharePoint , PowerQuery will of cause take the latest version. If you use another name, PowerQuery will simply ignore it.

Comment: Ok! Thank you! This is awesome! Know I have an new question which I will investigate!! I.e how to make my Power Query pick up the last file in a One drive folder. Or alternatively, how to make my query look at the date of a document in its name, and take the oldest! This is great! If you had given an answer I would accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the latest file from a SharePoint folder is a rather simple task in PowerQuery: If you're in MSTeams goto the files section of your channel and *"Open in SharePoint"*. Then you copy the first part of the path shown in your browser, everything before *"/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx ..."*

In PBI Desktop you select "Get Data" from *"SharePoint folder"* and paste the copied url. Then you filter the records to your needs and sort descending on the *"Date modified"* column. Eventually you pick *"Keep top rows"*, number=1, and by clicking on *"Binary"* in the *"Contents"* column you'll get your data.

Comment: Thank you. I am testing something along that line in three different configurations: on a file in my desktop (in this case my BPI refreshes only when I click refresh), on a file in a teams with what you describe for a published report (in that case the report refreshes daily).